# Connecting the Wifi dongle is freezing the linux system?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wifi, drivers, logs

I am a bit new to linux environment.

My Linux System is freezing when I am connecting to wifi dongle.

It works fine when I start the system without dongle, but the complete system hangs when I connect the dongle. And this freezing continues even when I disconnect the dongle. And it starts good if i disconnects it.

There are no logs generated on the issue but when i started to see on a different console using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> I could able to see some logs beginning with `RAX` `RSP` `RDX` following by some hex-code. Can someone help me to resolve it.

Here is the log of event.

```
[   63.138028] rfkill: input handler disabled
[  156.036073] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[  156.184685] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=2357, idProduct=010c, bcdDevice= 0.00
[  156.184690] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  156.184695] usb 1-1: Product: 802.11n NIC
[  156.184699] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: Realtek
[  156.184702] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 00E04C
[  156.207595] cfg80211: Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates for regulatory database
[  156.212245] cfg80211: Loaded X.509 cert 'sforshee: 00b28ddf47aef9cea7'
[  156.213369] lib80211: common routines for IEEE802.11 drivers
[  156.213370] lib80211_crypt: registered algorithm 'NULL'
[  156.225316] r8188eu: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[  156.226499] Chip Version Info: CHIP_8188E_Normal_Chip_TSMC_D_CUT_1T1R_RomVer(0)
[  156.249074] usbcore: registered new interface driver r8188eu
[  156.252787] r8188eu 1-1:1.0 wlx503eaaee9d84: renamed from wlan0
[  156.286137] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlx503eaaee9d84: link is not ready
[  156.652171] MAC Address = 50:3e:aa:ee:9d:84
[  156.653495] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlx503eaaee9d84: link is not ready
[  156.704200] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlx503eaaee9d84: link is not ready
[  159.521382] R8188EU: assoc success
[  165.100449] R8188EU: indicate disassoc
[  177.344301] R8188EU: assoc success
[  183.002009] R8188EU: indicate disassoc

[  184.403817] R8188EU: assoc success




[  188.862317] R8188EU: indicate disassoc
[  209.803686] R8188EU: assoc success
[  213.003386] R8188EU: indicate disassoc
[  233.005182] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlx503eaaee9d84: link is not ready
[  256.961652] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 3
[  260.576000] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[  260.724273] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=2357, idProduct=010c, bcdDevice= 0.00
[  260.724274] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  260.724275] usb 1-1: Product: 802.11n NIC
[  260.724276] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: Realtek
[  260.724277] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 00E04C0001
[  260.725253] Chip Version Info: CHIP_8188E_Normal_Chip_TSMC_D_CUT_1T1R_RomVer(0)
[  260.759240] r8188eu 1-1:1.0 wlx503eaaee9d84: renamed from wlan0
[  260.783747] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlx503eaaee9d84: link is not ready
[  261.148215] MAC Address = 50:3e:aa:ee:9d:84
[  261.149593] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlx503eaaee9d84: link is not ready
[  261.189816] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlx503eaaee9d84: link is not ready
```

Comment: Run `sudo dmesg -w` in a terminal and then plug your dongle in. Post the output here.

Comment: @JShorthouse I could not retrieve the records, the logs are being flushed as soon as I reboot the system

Comment: Everything in dmesg should also be logged to a file somewhere, I can't remember which file exactly but google will be able to help you.

Comment: Hello @JShorthouse , Finally I generated the above log using script. The log gets freezed at the "assoc success". Please let me know if you have any solution

Comment: Sorry, my knowledge of these kinds of issues ends at finding the right log output. You'll have to google the error you've found or hope that someone else comes by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also encounter the same situtation, not sure if it's too late to answer this question...

I solved this issue by disabling `system-monitor` of Gnome Shell Extension (I installed it by `apt install gnome-shell-extension-system-monitor`).